# Counting number of points in polygon using R?

Tags: r, sp

I have two classes sharing the same CRS (Latitute and Longitude):

1. `bolognaQuartieriMap`: a `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` containing data of a city boroughts.
2. `crashPoints`: a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` containing data of accidents.

They are well plotted using:

```
plot(bolognaQuartieriMap)
title("Crash per quartiere")
plot(crashPoints, col="red",add=TRUE)
```

What I need is to get the number of points (`crashPoints`) in each polygon that constitute `bolognaQuartieriMap`. I was suggested to use `over()` but I did not succeed.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you didn't provide a reproducible example nor an error message, see if this code snippet gets you started:

```
library("raster")
library("sp")

x <- getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=1)
class(x)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"

set.seed(1)
# sample random points
p <- spsample(x, n=300, type="random")
p <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(p, data.frame(id=1:300))

proj4string(x)
# [1] " +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj4string(p)
# [1] " +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"

plot(x)
plot(p, col="red" , add=TRUE)
```

[image: plot]

```
res <- over(p, x)
table(res$NAME_1) # count points
#               Abruzzo                Apulia            Basilicata
#                    11                    20                     9
#              Calabria              Campania        Emilia-Romagna
#                    16                     8                    25
# Friuli-Venezia Giulia                 Lazio               Liguria
#                     7                    14                     7
#             Lombardia                Marche                Molise
#                    22                     4                     3
#              Piemonte              Sardegna                Sicily
#                    35                    18                    21
#               Toscana   Trentino-Alto Adige                Umbria
#                    33                    15                     6
#         Valle d'Aosta                Veneto
#                     4                    22
```

Comment: I really really and really again appreciate this answer. Please give my upvote, a thousands thanks.

Comment: Tried to up vote really fast but didn't work. +100 for this answer. Great and works!

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same using the `sf` package. Check the reproducible and commented code below. The package `sf` is used to handle spatial objects as simple features objects. In this answer the package `raster` is used only for download example polygon data and the package `dplyr` for data transformation at the end.

```
# Load libraries ----------------------------------------------------------

library(raster)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

# Get sample data ---------------------------------------------------------

# Get polygon
polygon <- getData('GADM', country='URY', level = 1)[,1] # Download polygon of country admin level 1 
polygon <- st_as_sf(polygon) # convert to sf object
colnames(polygon) <- c("id_polygons", "geometry") # change colnames
polygon$id_polygons <- paste0("poly_", LETTERS[1:19]) #  change polygon ID

# Get sample random poins from polygon bbox
set.seed(4)
bbox <- st_as_sfc(st_bbox(polygon))
points <- st_sample(x = bbox, size = 100, type = "random")
points <- st_as_sf(data.frame(id_points = as.character(1:100)), points) # add points ID

# Plot data ---------------------------------------------------------------

# Plot polygon + points
plot(polygon, graticule = st_crs(4326), key.pos = 1)
plot(points, pch = 19, col = "black", add = TRUE)

# Intersection between polygon and points ---------------------------------

intersection <- st_intersection(x = polygon, y = points)

# Plot intersection
plot(polygon, graticule = st_crs(4326), key.pos = 1)
plot(intersection[1], col = "black", pch = 19, add = TRUE)

# View result
table(intersection$id_polygons) # using table

# using dplyr
int_result <- intersection %>% 
  group_by(id_polygons) %>% 
  count()

as.data.frame(int_result)[,-3]
```

[image: intersectionresult]

[image: intersectionplot]

Answer (score 2):

I want to leave another option. You can achieve the task using `poly.counts()` in the `GISTools` package. Using the sample data by rcs, you can do the following. If you'd look into the function, you'd realize that the function is written as `colSums(gContains(polys, pts, byid = TRUE))`. So, you can just use `gContains()` in the `rgeos` package and `colSums()`.

```
library(GISTools)

poly.counts(p, x) -> res
setNames(res, x@data$NAME_1)
```

Or

```
colSums(gContains(x, p, byid = TRUE)) -> res
setNames(res, x@data$NAME_1)
```

And the result is:

```
#              Abruzzo                Apulia            Basilicata 
#                   11                    20                     9 
#             Calabria              Campania        Emilia-Romagna 
#                   16                     8                    25 
#Friuli-Venezia Giulia                 Lazio               Liguria 
#                    7                    14                     7 
#            Lombardia                Marche                Molise 
#                   22                     4                     3 
#             Piemonte              Sardegna                Sicily 
#                   35                    18                    21 
#              Toscana   Trentino-Alto Adige                Umbria 
#                   33                    15                     6 
#        Valle d'Aosta                Veneto 
#                    4                    22
```

Comment: This was very helpful indeed. But I'm having trouble saving the results as I would like to plot a choropleth based on the number of points in the polygon