# Using R to combine long/lat data into UK region polygons?

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with geoinfo:

```
JobSeekerId   LocationId    UpdatedDt   EndDt   Latitude    Longitude   Country      Name         JobTitle                                                    CompanyName       
559098           3042091    05:20.2     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier    Funds of Funds financial controller                       AXA Private Equity       
2949016          3042091    43:05.7     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier                     Investment Manager                     Lloyds Banking Group       
2093684          3042091    12:42.7     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier                     Head of Compliance              Bank Leumi (Jersey) Limited       
3397729          3042091    01:20.3     NULL    49.18804    -2.10491    GB   Saint Helier                         Trust Officer      Kleinwort Benson, Fiduciary Services   
.
.
.
```

Now, I have a UK shapefile, loaded using readOGR from regdal:

```
ds <- readOGR(datdir, layer = "european_region_region")
```

that gives

```
> ds@data
                          NAME  AREA_CODE        DESCRIPTIO                  FILE_NAME   NUMBER NUMBER0 POLYGON_ID UNIT_ID      CODE    HECTARES       AREA TYPE_CODE             DESCRIPT0     TYPE_COD0    DESCRIPT1
0          Eastern Euro Region        EUR   European Region        EASTERN_EURO_REGION        1       2     124430   41425 E15000006 1958623.344  45150.544        VA      CIVIL VOTING AREA          <NA>        <NA>
1    East Midlands Euro Region        EUR   European Region  EAST_MIDLANDS_EURO_REGION        1       2     124952   41423 E15000004 1581093.950  16766.722        VA      CIVIL VOTING AREA          <NA>        <NA>
2           London Euro Region        EUR   European Region         LONDON_EURO_REGION        1       2     124433   41428 E15000007  159469.727   2118.277        VA      CIVIL VOTING AREA          <NA>        <NA>
.
.
.
```

What I'd like to do is to generate a plot where I'd get the sum of entries in each geographical region/polygon. I'd like to get the number of users within the London region, for example.

Is there a straightforward way of joining the data and the shapefile via the geo coordinates?

Comment: See this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117/counts-the-number-of-points-in-a-polygon-in-r/

Comment: To join the data you need a common field (a key) across both the dataset you have (the csv) and the shapefile. The shapefile looks like it contains standard geographical IDs (`CODE`) but these don't match to your `LocationId' in the csv. Can you explain what the LocationId is in an edit: this might still be usable by conversion. Thanks.

Comment: @rcs - is there a way to use my own shapefile rather than via getData in raster()?

Phil - alas the LocationID is an internal reference that I have no access to. I thought as much that a join would be required, but I've nothing to join as it stands.

Comment: Yes, you just need spatial objects in R. Convert your CSV data set (`x`) to a SpatialPointsDataFrame `coordinates(x) <- ~ Longitude + Longitude` ... can you provide your data/shapefile?

Comment: Thanks! The shapefile is here: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B207R1Gt7uCOflhCYi15U29xbU8tNllYdkZvdHZuRXVXaTltcGpFTmNJTloySW5xSGJITGs&usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Counting number of points in polygon using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117) does what you want, but I thought I'd add to it to show how to join the counts back to the polygons.

My interpretation is that you want to count the number of points within regions, where regions is defined by the NAME attribute of your shapefile. However, your shapefile has many features for each region (i.e. NAME), which is worth keeping in mind. In particular, you have 2798 features within your shapefile and only 11 unique values of the NAME attribute (i.e. regions).

Here's one approach, which basically involves duplicating the counts for a given region across all polygon features for that region. It seems to me that you'd want to be careful doing this since you end up with so much duplication of data. I'm no expert though, so maybe someone else can comment on this:

```
# Much of this taken from: 
# https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117/counts-the-number-of-points-in-a-polygon-in-r/
library(raster)
library(maptools)

# Shapefile - in subdirectory "data" of your working directory
# raster::shapefile is a convenient wrapper for readOGR
x <- shapefile('data/european_region_region.shp')

# Create some random points within UK
set.seed(100)
p <- spsample(x, n=100, type="random")
p <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(p, data.frame(id=1:100, JobSeekerId=559098:(559098+99)))
# Write out to a .csv file to match the set up of the question
write.csv(data.frame(p), file="data/points.csv")

# Read data in and make a SpatialPointsDataFrame
p <- read.csv("data/points.csv")
coordinates(p) <- ~x + y # For you this would be ~Longitude + Latitude
projection(p) <- crs(x)

# Polygon attributes at points
res <- over(p, x)
# Number of points within each "NAME" attribute
cnts <- data.frame(table(res$NAME))
names(cnts)[1] <- 'NAME'

# Join counts back to the polygons based on NAME
# Note that this will duplicate values
xFreq <- merge(x, cnts, by='NAME')
# Fill 0 where NA, these regions had no points overlapping
xFreq@data[is.na(xFreq@data$Freq),] <- 0
```

Another approach would be to merge all polygons with the same NAME attribute, then proceed from there as above. This avoids the duplication:

```
xUnion <- unionSpatialPolygons(x, IDs=x$NAME)
xUnion <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(xUnion, 
                data.frame(NAME=row.names(xUnion), row.names=row.names(xUnion)))
res <- over(p, xUnion)
cnts <- data.frame(table(res$NAME))
names(cnts)[1] <- 'NAME'
xFreq <- merge(xUnion, cnts, by='NAME')
```

The issue here is that you loose attribute information when using `unionSpatialPolygons`. So, you'd have to join back in all the attributes that are common between regions with same NAME.