# How to do operation after using over() for a shapefile in R?

Tags: shapefile, r, csv

I am copying the answer of [Counts the number of points in a polygon in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117/counts-the-number-of-points-in-a-polygon-in-r/110246)

```
library("raster")
x <- getData('GADM', country='ITA', level=1)
class(x)
# [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
# attr(,"package")
# [1] "sp"
set.seed(1)
# sample random points
p <- spsample(x, n=300, type="random")
p <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(p, data.frame(id=1:300))
proj4string(x)
# [1] " +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
proj4string(p)
# [1] " +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0"
plot(x)
plot(p, col="red" , add=TRUE)
res <- over(p, x)
table(res$NAME_1)
```

You see a nice overlapping of the `+` on the map (refer to that answer). I have similar data sets but in addition to `id` in the CSV file other two columns `bh` and `dk`.  What I need is just to compute the mean for all the values of `id`, `bh`, `dk` for each polygon. Any idea on this. In other words, in that answer he returned the number of points for each polygon using `table(res$NAME_1)`, while here I need to calculate the mean for all values within a polygon.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate` for spatial aggregation (`sp:::aggregate.Spatial`, see `?aggregate.Spatial`):

```
aggregate(p, by=x, FUN=mean)
```

Here is short example for Austria (I cannot download the boundaries of Italy, the GADM server is down at the moment):

```
library("raster")
x <- getData('GADM', country='AUT', level=1)

# sample data
set.seed(1)
n <- 300
p <- spsample(x, n=n, type="random")
dat <- data.frame(id=seq_len(n), bh=rnorm(n), dk=rnorm(n))
p <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(p, data=dat)

# spatial aggregation by state
res <- aggregate(p, by=x, FUN=mean)
res
# class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
# features    : 9 
# extent      : 9.534, 17.16, 46.37, 49.02  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0 
# variables   : 3
# names       :               id,                 bh,                 dk 
# min values  : 99.6666666666667, -0.210505172806924, -0.417346917880549 
# max values  :         170.1875,  0.430844459509317,  0.306769666801599 
as.data.frame(res)
#       id       bh       dk
# 1 170.19 -0.01382 -0.41735
# 2 164.18 -0.21051  0.06174
# 3 141.84 -0.12476 -0.05628
# 4 153.72 -0.13667  0.30677
# 5 147.67  0.28379  0.19070
# 6 152.60  0.20133 -0.15972
# 7 149.62  0.06406  0.05419
# 8 139.60  0.07352 -0.24318
# 9  99.67  0.43084 -0.27157
```

or manually using `over()`:

```
state <- over(p, x)$ID_1
aggregate(cbind(id, bh, dk) ~ state, p, FUN=mean)
#   state     id       bh       dk
# 1     1 170.19 -0.01382 -0.41735
# 2     2 164.18 -0.21051  0.06174
# 3     3 141.84 -0.12476 -0.05628
# 4     4 153.72 -0.13667  0.30677
# 5     5 147.67  0.28379  0.19070
# 6     6 152.60  0.20133 -0.15972
# 7     7 149.62  0.06406  0.05419
# 8     8 139.60  0.07352 -0.24318
# 9     9  99.67  0.43084 -0.27157
```

Comment: Thanks rcs. How can I just assign all points to the corresponding polygon before aggregation. for example in your second solution(which worked for me) same thing but before aggregation and for all points. add as many as columns in x to p?