# Counting how many times a point is inside a set of intersecting polygons in R

Tags: r, point-in-polygon, sp

I have a set of points (latitude and longitude) and a set of polygons with the same CRS. Since some of the polygons are interescting, it may be that some of the points are in more than one polygon.

How can I count how many times a point lies in all the set of polygons?

```
inside <- data.frame(as.numeric(!is.na(over(points, as(get(polygons), "SpatialPolygons")))))
```

This line of code works only to generate a dummy variable equal to 1 if the point is contained in at least a polygon and 0 otherwise.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117/counts-the-number-of-points-in-a-polygon-in-r?rq=1

Comment: @mdsumner The code in that post counts how many points are inside a certain polygon (the polygons - Italy's regions - do not intercept). Here, what I am trying to find is how many times a point lies inside a different polygon (since the polygons can intersect).

Comment: Ok, whoops. Use the code there to build up an example so we don't have to do it for you. Feel free to ask about making a reproducible example if you need.

Comment: For example, if a point intersects 4 overlapping polygons, that point should be assigned a value of 4? For each point, count the number of intersecting polygons?

Comment: `over` has an argument, `returnList = TRUE`, that gives you all intersections instead of the first. Alternatively, swap `x` and `y` in `over` and see what that gives you.

Comment: Yes @Aaron this is exactly the variable I want to generate for each point of my data set but I haven't found out an adequate code yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the times one point is in a polygon or in different polygons with simple `R` functions using `base` and `sp` packages. With the reproducible example below you can:

1. Identify and count the times one point is inside a set of polygons
2. Identify which point/polygon intersects

### Load libraries and make some example data:

```
# Load libraries
library("sp")
library("raster")

# Example coords
coordsPoly1 <- data.frame('x' = c(-63.8, -40.9, -40.7, -63.5, -63.8), 'y' = c(-30.1, -30.1, -37.4, -37.1, -30.1))
coordsPoly2 <- data.frame('x' = c(-47.1, -38.4, -37.3, -46.6, -47.1), 'y' = c(-28.7, -28.6, -47.1, -46.6, -28.7))
coordsPoly3 <- data.frame('x' = c(-48.4, -28.0, -27.4, -48.1, -48.4), 'y' = c(-40.9, -40.9, -49.6, -49.4, -40.9))
coordsPoly4 <- data.frame('x' = c(-49.7, -29.4, -28.6, -48.9, -49.7), 'y' = c(-25.6, -25.8, -39.1, -38.8, -25.6)) 

# Coords to SpatialPolygons objects    
polygons <- SpatialPolygons(Srl = list(Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordsPoly1)), ID = "1"), 
                                       Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordsPoly2)), ID = "2"), 
                                       Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordsPoly3)), ID = "3"),
                                       Polygons(srl = list(Polygon(coords = coordsPoly4)), ID = "4")))

# Make sample points 
points <- spsample(polygons, n = 10, type = "random")
```

### Plot polygons and points:

```
plot(polygons, border = c("#EF2929", "#729FCF", "#8AE234", "#AD7FA8"), lwd = 3, 
     xlab = "Longitude", ylab = "Latitude", main = "Plot polygons")
text(polygons, labels = seq_along(polygons), col = c("#EF2929", "#729FCF", "#8AE234", "#AD7FA8"), cex = 4)
plot(points, pch = 19, add = TRUE)
text(points, labels = seq_along(points), pos = 3)
box()
```

[image: examplePlot]

### Spatial Query: points in polygon

```
pointsInPolygons <- sp::over(x = points, y = polygons, returnList = TRUE)

# Count times in polygon
counting <- lapply(pointsInPolygons, FUN = function(x) length(x))

df <- data.frame("point" = rownames(t(do.call("cbind", counting))), 
                 "count" = t(do.call("cbind", counting)), 
                 "polygon" = paste(pointsInPolygons))

> df
   point count polygon
1      1     1       2
2      2     1       4
3      3     1       3
4      4     2 c(2, 4)
5      5     2 c(1, 4)
6      6     2 c(1, 4)
7      7     1       2
8      8     1       4
9      9     1       1
10    10     1       4
```

**Note:** your plot and example points will be different because the `spsample` function generates random sampling each time.

Comment: Thank you very much @Guzmán for the detailed reply! In the meanwhile, I came out with a possible solution to the problem I had using the function "returnList=T".

`list <- over(points, polygons, "SpatialPolygons"), returnList = T)
count <- data.frame(sapply(list,length))`