# Trying to count points in polygon and add a column to the table

Tags: r, geos

I have a data variable called "schools" with the following data.

```
| School Name | Address | geometry              |
|---------------------------------------------- |
| School A    | 123 abc | c(123.321, 456,654)   |
| School B    | 321 cba | c(222.111, 333,444)   |
| School C    | 111 aaa | c(111.111, 222.222)   |
|-----------------------------------------------|
```

and the next variable is called "student_population"

```
| Region  | population | geometry |
|------------------------------------------|
| central | 2 | list(list(c(122.111, 333.111, 212, 321))) |
| West | 3 | list(list(c(122.111, 333.111, 212, 321, 112.331, 222.232))) |
| East | 2 | list(list(c(122.111, 333.111, 212, 321))) |
```

[image: I tm_shape to display the student_population as shown]

[image: i plot(schools) to show the points. Both student_population and schools have the same crs]

I want to count the number of schools in each region. hence, in the end i would get a table of the following

```
| Region  | population | number of schools in region | geometry |
|-----------------|-------------------------|
| central | 2 | 10 | list(list(c(122.111, 333.111, 212, 321))) |
| West | 3 | 20 |list(list(c(122.111, 333.111, 212, 321, 112.331, 222.232))) |
| East | 2 | 10 | list(list(c(122.111, 333.111, 212, 321))) |
```

I hope I am clear in explaining what I have done and what I want. I am having trouble solving this. In the end, I wish to `tm_shape` it. Tried using `st_within` but I do not know how to use it.

Comment: How about the accepted answer of [Counting number of points in polygon using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117/counting-number-of-points-in-polygon-using-r?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you! st_intersection is the function i am looking for.