# Error message when joining two dataframes with sf -Error: y should be a data.frame; for spatial joins, use st_join

Tags: r, attribute-joins, spatial-join, sf

In R, I'm trying to count the number of points which fall within a buffer around polygons and add the count result to the original shapefile from which the polygon file was created. I've followed the answer provided by @Guzmán from this question: [Counting number of points in polygon using R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110117/counting-number-of-points-in-polygon-using-r). Everything works fine until it comes to adding the result to the original shapefile, which I want to do based on the attribute "ID", i.e. not a spatial join. I get the error message "Error: y should be a data.frame; for spatial joins, use st_join" even though y is a dataframe (at least it is according to `is.data.frame`).

````r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)


OrigPolys <- st_read("OrigPolys.shp") #Load polygons
Points <- st_read("Points.shp") #Load points
NewPolys <- subset(OrigPolys, X1 != 'NA') #Subset required polygons
Buffer <- st_buffer(NewPolys, 5000) #Create buffer NewPolys
inter <- st_intersection(Buffer, Points) #Find points in NewPolys
int_count <- inter %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  count() #Count number of Points in Buffer
as.data.frame(int_count) #Convert to df (not sure if this is required as is.data.frame = T whether included or not)
OrigPolys_Pts <- left_join(OrigPolys, int_count, by = "ID") #Join count to OrigPolys based on "ID" attribute```
````

Comment: Well, an sf object can be both a data.frame and a spatial object. Looking at `class(x)` is a more reliable way to look at object classes. Have you tried following the advice in the error, which is very rare for R, and tried using `st_join`. If you are, in fact, dealing with two spatial objects it should return what you are after.

Answer (score 1):

Better Try `int_count=st_drop_geometry(int_count)` before performing the join. Geometries are sticky in `sf`, meaning that they would be in the object unless you explicitly erase them.